# Adding foreign input to angular module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an external script that generates an extra input tag for my form. In some cases it adds some data in that input. Also, the tag is dynamically created and does not exist at startup.

I do not have any control over the script creating the input tag.

Can I somehow add `ng-model` tag to that extra input? What are my options to be able to use the data added in that extra field?

**Edit**
I know how to read the value (`getElementById`), but I would like to use it for dynamic form validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add event listeners on input elements, and update `$scope` models in event handler:

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/NuDX5d0Pp7wop3hQm4Ig?p=preview)

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#test')).on('keyup', function(event){
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.inputText = event.target.value;
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the foreign input has an id attribute.

the simplest way to access the data is to capture the data on form submit or any event after the script has been executed.

```
$scope.formSubmit = function(){
   $scope.myform.generatedInput = document.getElementById('generatedElementId').value || null;

  /* ...
   Your Code here
  ... */

}
```

Comment: I am sorry for not specifying. I would like to use this data for dynamic form validation. Your solution works perfectly, but is not suitable for my use-case.